# Matplotlib plot histogram of fair die

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, histogram

I'm trying to display a histogram of the probability density of throwing a fair die. Basically there should be 6 bars and each with height 1/6, equally spaced. I tried this:

```
fair = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]*100)
plt.hist(fair, density=True, label='Fair Die')
plt.show()
```

and I also tried this

```
plt.hist(fair, bins=11, density=True, label='Fair Die', align='mid')
```

but it doesn't seem to work. I don't understand why the hist command doesn't make the correct histogram by default, it is such a simple histogram.

Comment: I think a bar plot would be way easier here

Comment: What is the relevance of `*100` here? I don't see a need of histogram here

Comment: No particular relevance for this. That was there because my overall goal is to create some plots for Importance Sampling using a fair die to estimate the mean of a biased die.  Probably I could remove that 100

Comment: @Euler_Salter or show a truly probabilistic die: see **Bonus** part of my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue here are the bins.

You want to avoid binning any two (or more) values together, otherwise your density will be a multiple of 1/6.

Here is how to set the bins right:

```
fair = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]*100)
plt.hist(fair, density=True, bins=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7], label='Fair Die', rwidth=0.9, align='left')  # rwidth is optional
plt.show()
```

From [the docs](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html):

> bins : array
>
> The edges of the bins. Length nbins + 1 (nbins left edges and right edge of last bin). Always a single array even when multiple data sets are passed in.

Note: If you want the label to be shown, call `plt.legend()` before the `plt.show()`.

Note 2: In this case it's kinda recommended to set `rwidth` < binsize as otherwise there is no space between the bins and here all bis are of equal dimension, thus it all appears as a single block. **Have a look at the comments to see how this confuses people :P**

Alternatively you could draw a border around the bars:

```
plt.hist(fair, density=True, bins=range(1,8), label='Fair Die', edgecolor='white', linewidth=1.2)
```

[image]

**Bonus:**

In case you want to have a [stochastic representation of your fair dice](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.random_integers.html):

```
fair_proba = np.random.random_integers(1,6, 1000)
```

[image]

Comment: Always try your code before you post as an answer. See the plot first for yourself I would suggest

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, I get basically one big vertical bar

Comment: @Euler_Salter add `rwidth=0.9' as argument. This will clear things up.

Comment: @Bazingaa code is fresh from the terminal...

Comment: Does your code generate any figure? Does it look like 6 individual bars or even close to a histogram?

Comment: @Bazingaa I suggest you copy paste it and you'll see

Comment: Ok now you added width. It wasn’t there previously

Comment: @Bazingaa it was just as correct previously as it is now. Previously the bars were just stuck together, seeming to be one single bar. But they never were. **This answer was never wrong!** Just not very pretty at some point. It's kinda unfair to downvote.

Comment: How can I make the bars centered? At the moment they are in between

Comment: Oh okay you need to use align='left'

Comment: @Euler_Salter exactly! was just adding it to the answer.

Comment: Also you can try using range(1,8) instead of writing all numbers in a list manually

Comment: I think Bazingaa helped you improve the code, and because of the previous downvote, I upvoted because it certainly doesn't deserve downvote.

Answer (score 3):

```
In [10]: fair = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]*100)
    ...: bins = np.array([i/2 for i in range(-1, 14)])
    ...: plt.hist(fair, bins=bins, label='Fair Die', align='left')
    ...: plt.xlim([0, 7])
    ...: plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to align them with the label in the center? I tried align=mid, which kinda works, but it leaves a weird blank space on the left

Comment: Use align='left'

Comment: Still leaves a weird space in and the labels are wrong, the dice can't roll a 0

Comment: You need to play with the code to get what you want. I edited the code for the sake of completeness, but it's not a good practice.